# A strange predicate that cannot prove assertion already defined in body

Tags: verification, dafny

Suppose we have a datatype called `Tree`, and a function `size` to calculate its size

```
datatype Tree = Empty | Node(key: int, left: Tree, right: Tree)
function size(t: Tree): (s: nat)
{
  match t
  case Empty => 0
  case Node(_, l, r) => size(l) + size(r) + 1
}
```

Now for some reasons, I wanna let this tree be somehow "balanced". Specifically, that is

```
predicate alpha_weight_balanced(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
{
  if t == Empty then true
  else
    size(t.left) as real <= alpha*(size(t) as real)
    && size(t.right) as real <= alpha*(size(t) as real)
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.left,alpha)
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.right,alpha)
}
```

When `alpha_weight_balanced` holds, the size of each child of tree `t` is less than `alpha*size(t)`.
And naturally, this lemma should hold

```
lemma test(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
  requires alpha_weight_balanced(t, alpha)
  requires t != Empty
  ensures size(t.left) as real <= alpha*(size(t) as real)
{}
```

However, dafny could not prove this "obvious" lemma. I even tried wrap `size` like

```
function f(a: int): int
// there is no implemetion for `f`

predicate alpha_weight_balanced(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
{
  if t == Empty then true
  else
    f(size(t.left)) as real <= alpha*f(size(t)) as real
    && f(size(t.right)) as real <= alpha*f(size(t)) as real
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.left,alpha)
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.right,alpha)
}

lemma test(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
  requires alpha_weight_balanced(t, alpha)
  requires t != Empty
  ensures     f(size(t.left)) as real <= alpha*f(size(t)) as real
              && f(size(t.right)) as real <= alpha*f(size(t)) as real
{
}
```

And dafny proves this successfully. But if I modify the function `f`

```
function f(a: int): int
ensures f(a) == a
```

The proof failed again.

I'm so confused about it, anyone knows why?

Comment: I am not exactly sure if it is the problem but it does seem to me that if one branch has alpha percentage of nodes then the opposite branch should have 1-alpha percentage.

Comment: Yes, but since alpha is in [0.5, 1) , alpha is larger than 1-alpha, so the inequalities should both hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid verification failure is to hide real number multiplication inside function. Reason you don't require this when doing such verification in nat and int is dafny does automatically for you.

```
datatype Tree = Empty | Node(key: int, left: Tree, right: Tree)

function size(t: Tree): (s: nat)
{
  match t
  case Empty => 0
  case Node(_, l, r) => size(l) + size(r) + 1
}

function multiply(a: real, b: real): real { a * b }

predicate alpha_weight_balanced(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
{
  if t == Empty then true
  else
    size(t.left) as real <= multiply(alpha, size(t) as real)
    && size(t.right) as real <= multiply(alpha, size(t) as real)
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.left,alpha)
    && alpha_weight_balanced(t.right,alpha)
}

lemma test(t: Tree, alpha: real)
  requires 0.5 <= alpha < 1.0
  requires alpha_weight_balanced(t, alpha)
  requires t != Empty
  ensures size(t.left) as real <= multiply(alpha, size(t) as real)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But I still wonder why `*` need to be hided, Is this because some special designed mechanism?

Comment: Reason for hiding * is you don''t need non linear arithmetic machinery of z3 as what you required to prove is already given to you as precondition. Hiding * avoid non linear arithmetic logic.